# SSL certificate for oauth 2.0?

Tags: ssl, oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate

Recently, I came to know that, **SSL certificate** is mandatory to use **Oauth 2.0**.

My question is, **[Comodo PositiveSSL](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/domain-validation.aspx)** (which costs 9$) certificate is enough to use Oauth 2.0??

For a new website that has the potential of having high traffic in near future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work just fine (assuming your browser does not complain when you visit your site with `https://...`).

You can use any certificate (including self-signed) as long as all browsers you need to use with your site trust that certificate (or any root certificate in the chain). I.e. for you local testing you may use any certificate and simply ignore validation errors, in organization you may install your own certificates. For regular internet users you need any valid SSL certificate issued by trusted authority as you really should not ask your users to install your self-signed certificates.

Comment: So SSL certificate has nothing to do with the traffic of the website?
My main priority is to use Oauth 2.0, for heavy traffic website. So i can go with that??

Comment: Not sure what your comment "SSL certificate has nothing to do with the traffic of the website" is about... SSL certificate essentially just says "the domain name of this site is XXXXX" and it is up to user/browser to trust that information or not. I.e. if can scribble your name on piece of paper or use goverment issued document (like passport) to say "this is my identification" - most people will trust passport (as "signed" be government), but you and your friends may be ok with just piece of paper you wrote/sign.

Comment: If your comment was about impact on server - HTTPS SSL traffic requires encryption (irrespective of where/how you got the certificate) and as such it requires more resources that regular HTTP traffic. Should you be concerned about it - your call.

Comment: Ok i got that, so why there are more certificate types with different costs, is that all about more security or for any other needs??

Comment: I have no idea what type of cert you get for different cost - never needed to find/pay myself. Check related questions for more info - mainly you need to know if your certificate is signed by "trusted root authority" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). Some price difference may come from type of cert (SAN or wildcard certs would likely cost way more than 3rd level sub-domain).